# Why is Python 2 input() giving me 'NameError: name "____" is not defined'?

Tags: python, input, python-2.x

I'm trying to write a function that will ask for name, last name and year of birth. Also, it will later print out the initials and the age.

First of all, it doesn't ask for any of it.

Second of all, it doesn't matter what I'll enter it will print the error:

```
NameError: name "____"  is not defined.
```

I'm using Python 3.

Here is the code:

```
def userinfo():
    name_ = input("Enter your first name: ")
    last_ = input("Enter your last name: ")
    year_ = input("Enter your year: ")
    initials_ = name_[0] + last_[0]
    age_ = (2018 - year_)
    _info = ("Your initials are ") + (initials_) + (" and you are ") + (str(age_)) + (" years old.")
    if (len(name_) > 0 and len(last_) > 0 and len(year_) > 0 and name_.isalpha() and last_.isalpha()):
        return (_info)
    else:
        return ("Error")
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the full code. Please provide a [mcve] so we can diagnose your problem. Thank you.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you, please provide a complete code example that reproduces the error you are asking about. The code you have given so far cannot possible cause that error.

Comment: It doesn't ask for any of it presumably because you just defined the function and did not call it. To do so, just put `userinfo()` **after** the function definition **outside** the function.

Comment: By running this code I try and enter for example "Marina" and I get that error

Comment: Are you ***sure*** you're not using python 2?

Comment: Because you're accidentally using Python 2, where `input()` tries to eval'uate its input, i.e. assumes it's a variable name and tries to look it up. Python 2 `raw_input` = Python 3 `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rectified code with some corrections:

1) Replacing `input` with `raw_input` (assuming you are using `python 2.***`). In case you are using version `3+`, then replace back `raw_input` by `input`.

2) Replacing `year_` by `int(year_)` while calculating the age because user input is of type `str`.

```
def userinfo():
    name_ = raw_input("Enter your first name: ")
    last_ = raw_input("Enter your last name: ")
    year_ = raw_input("Enter your year: ")
    print (name_)
    initials_ = name_[0] + last_[0]
    age_ = (2018 - int(year_))  # Correction here
    _info = ("Your initials are ") + (initials_) + (" and you are ") + (str(age_)) + (" years old.")
    if (len(name_) > 0 and len(last_) > 0 and len(year_) > 0 and name_.isalpha() and last_.isalpha()):
        return (_info)
    else:
        return ("Error") 

userinfo()
```

**Output**

```
Enter your first name: Donald
Enter your last name: Trump
Enter your year: 1950
Donald
'Your initials are DT and you are 68 years old.'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be thrown from declaration of `main()`.

Check the main function whether you used double underscore( __ ) or triple underscore( ___ ).

the correct synax is `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Hope this helps! Cheers!